# How to delete only user meta value (not key) from usermeta table in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, meta-query, user-meta, meta-value

I store multiple image in media library and save its id in wp_usermeta table. my metakey is 'images' and meta value in like '279,280,281'. Now I get the image from table like this:

```
<?php $images = get_the_author_meta( 'images', $user->ID );
   $images = explode(',',$images);
   foreach($images as $img) {
?>
          <img src="<?=wp_get_attachment_url( $img );?>" width="100" height="100" />
          <a href="<?php  echo get_edit_user_link( $user->ID ); ?>&image_id=<?= $img;?    >">Delete</a>
      <?php } ?>
```

Now, I wont to delete particular id from table and also remove image from uploads folder(media library). So, please help me to solve it. I try this type of code for delete:

```
 <a href="<?php  echo get_edit_user_link( $user->ID ); ?>&image_id=<?= $img;?>">Delete</a>
      <?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['image_id'])){
    delete_usermeta( $user->ID, $meta_value = $img ); 
 <?php wp_delete_attachment( $img); ?> 
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the ID then.

```
$images = get_the_author_meta( 'images', $user->ID );
$images = explode(',',$images);
```

$images is an Array isn't it? Then I hope this one can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array

Comment: Personally, I avoided to use $wpdb->query as much as possible. Besides DELETE query will delete one (or some) row(s) which is mean it's not what you want. If you want to change the meta_value you could use UPDATE query. Still I recommend you to use Wordpress function to do that.

Comment: I create code as your suggested code as follow but still not working:  <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['image_id'])){
  $image_id = $_REQUEST['image_id'];
 
    if (($key = array_search($image_id, $images)) !== false) {
    unset($images[$key]);
} } ?>

Comment: Use update user meta to change images value..
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Comment: I try to re-create your code. 
http://pastebin.com/w2PdxZvc
And please don't put this code inside looping. Just put it after get_header() function.